# How to model double relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, filemaker

Background: I have designed a solution for Filemaker to input data into a Question Database.

After we are done with inputting data into Filemaker, we will be exporting the data as excel and transferring it into an online system probably running on ASP.NET or PHP

Part of it looks like this:

```
Knowledge Table:
Knowledge ID (Primary Key),
Description,
Knowledge Type

Method Table:
Method ID (Primary Key),
Step,
Step Knowledge ID
```

For example. The "Find Acceleration method" Knowledge can have 3 steps:

1. Find unknown velocity
2. Find unknown time
3. Apply acceleration formula

Each of these steps is also a record in the Knowledge Table, i.e., the steps are knowledges in Knowledge Table.

How do I model the double relationship between Knowledge Table and Method Knowledge Step Table?

Currently, I thought of 2 ways:

1. Knowledge Table::Knowledge ID -- Method Table::Method ID relationship AND Knowledge Table::Knowledge ID --< Method Table::Step Knowledge ID
2. Creating another instance of Knowledge Table and link the Knowledge ID separately to Method Table: Step Knowledge ID.

I'm really not too sure of what is the best way of doing it.

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship between Method and Knowledge? Is it (1:1): "every Method is a Knowledge but some Knowledge are not Methods". Or (1:n): "every Method belongs to a Knowledge (a method is a Knowledge step) and every Knowledge has one or more steps (Methods)" Or (n:m) "every Method can belong to one or more Knowledges and every Knowledge has one or more steps (Methods)"?

Comment: Or there are 2 different relationships between the two entities?

Comment: It could also be an optional relationship - i.e. each Knowledge has [0..n] Methods and each Method has [0..n] Knowledges. (i.e. "every" might be overly restrictive)

Comment: Is this a [bill of materials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials), perhaps?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why your "Methods" must also be in the "Knowledge" table. Is this actually necessary? How do you plan to use this data?

Comment: @ypercube simon:Every Method is a Knowledge but some Knowledge are not Methods. But Every Method will have steps which are Knowledges themselves... and Each Method can have Many steps. Sorry for replying so late, stack exchange is not sending me notification on comments. onedaywhen don't think it has the same structure as a BOM. frustratedwithformsdesigner: We plan to use Methods as a way to generate more questions for students..

Comment: @zerlphr: How do you plan to use a Method to generate new questions?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner The reason why i broke Method down into Steps was due to some knowledges being part of Method and hence it created some redundancies when we have 1 or more Knowledge and 1 or more Method for each question. Method will be used the same way to generate Question as Knowledge. Basically, the system will query for questions with the same knowledge and display it for students to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `Knowledge` *might* be a `Method`, I'm wondering if it would make more sense to store them both in the same table:

```
KnowledgeAndMethods
--------------------
  ID - unique primary key
  Description
  parent_knowledge - nullable (for methods that are both a Method and a Knowledge, this is the Knowledge that the Method belongs to)
  knowledge_type
  Step
  Step_ID
```

Based on your example, I think the data would be stored as:

```
ID Description                  Parent_knowledge  Step      Step ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1 "Find Accel. Method"
2 "Find unknown velocity"         1               "Step 1"     S1
3 "Find unknown time"             2               "Step 2"     S2
4 "Apply acceleration formula"    3               "Step 3"     S3
5 "Land rocket ship"
```

With recursive queries, it could be very easy to get data back from this kind of table.

You could have a KnowledgeSubtype or MethodSubtype column if you want, but I'm not sure if you would gain anything.

---

Based on comments, it sounds like a many-to-many relationship is wanted. So here's another try at it:

```
KnowledgeAndMethods
--------------------
  ID - unique primary key
  Description
  parent_knowledge - nullable (for methods that are both a Method and a Knowledge, this is the Knowledge that the Method belongs to)
  knowledge_type

Methods_Steps
  Parent_Knowledge_ID - the ID of the parent Knowledge
  Step
  Step_ID - The ID local within a set of Steps
  Method_ID  - The ID of the Method that is a Knowledge
```

So now the previous example might look like:

```
KnowledgeAndMethods:

ID Description                  
--------------------------------
1 "Find Accel. Method"
2 "Find unknown velocity"       
3 "Find unknown time"           
4 "Apply acceleration formula"  

Methods_Steps:
Knowledge_ID  Step      Step_ID    Method_ID
--------------------------------------------
1             "Step 1"  1          2
1             "Step 2"  2          3
1             "Step 3"  3          4
5             "Step 9"  6          2   <---- Here's an example of "Find Unknown Velocity" being a different "Step" in a diffent "Knowledge"
```

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. So Step and Step ID are nullable too... But 1 problem is that "Find unknown velocity" can also be a step of another Method...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two things:

- Break the `Method` into 2 tables (`Method` and details, say `MethodStep`)
- Use the supertype/subtype pattern with `Knowledge` as supertype and `Method` and `MethodStep` (and possibly other you may have) as subtypes.

Design details:

```
KnowledgeSubtype_Ref
--------------------
KnowledgeSubtype    CHAR(1)
Description
PRIMARY KEY (KnowledgeSubtype) 

INSERT INTO KnowledgeSubtype_Ref
    VALUES  
      ('M', 'Method') ,
      ('S', 'Method Step') ,
      .... ;                   --- other subtypes of Knowledge   

Knowledge
---------
KnowledgeID         INT  AUTO_INCREMENT
KnowledgeSubtype    CHAR(1)
Description 
KnowledgeType
PRIMARY KEY (KnowledgeID) 
UNIQUE KEY (KnowledgeID, KnowledgeSubtype) 
FOREIGN KEY (KnowledgeSubtype) 
    REFERENCES KnowledgeSubtype_Ref (KnowledgeSubtype) 

Method
------
MethodID            INT                 --- no  AUTO_INCREMENT
KnowledgeSubtype    DEFAULT 'M'
PRIMARY KEY (MethodID) 
FOREIGN KEY (MethodID, KnowledgeSubtype) 
    REFERENCES Knowledge (KnowledgeID, KnowledgeSubtype) 

MethodStep
----------
MethodStepID        INT                 --- no  AUTO_INCREMENT
KnowledgeSubtype    DEFAULT 'S'
MethodID
Step
PRIMARY KEY (MethodStepID)
UNIQUE KEY (MethodID, Step) 
FOREIGN KEY (MethodStepID, KnowledgeSubtype)
    REFERENCES Knowledge (KnowledgeID, KnowledgeSubtype) 
FOREIGN KEY (MethodID) 
    REFERENCES Method (MethodID)
```

Comment: Hi @ypercube, a Knowledge may or may not be a method. Hence, i'm thinking whether I should include KnowledgeSubType in Knowledge Table (There will be many knowledges that are not methods). Also i have 3 main types of Knowledges in Knowledge Type field (Factual, Conceptual and Procedural) but all three can be a method too, so adding Method as a value in Knowledge Type field might not work.

Comment: @zelphr: I kept your `KnowledgeType` that would store your classification and differentiate between (Factual, Conceptual, Procedural).

Comment: The `KnowledgeSubtype` could keep `M` for Method, `S` for MethodStep, `O` for other (subtypes). So, you will have 2 classifications, independent of each other.

Comment: Hmmm those are good advice... i need some time to see if it can be applied to my database! thanks ypercube!

Comment: i need some time to see if it can be applied to my database! thanks ypercube! So will that mean there are 2 relationships: Knowledge -- Method -- Method Step and Knowledge -- Method Step? Will there be any drawbacks?